# Pair of messages: SUCCSSFUL but also NOT FOUND when reading artifact from Local Maven Repo

Tags: maven, sbt

I installed a file locally using mvn install

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file  -Dfile=c:\shared\kafka-0.7.2-spark.jar  -DgroupId=org.apache.kafka -DartifactId=kafka -Dversion=0.7.2-spark  -Dpackaging=jar
```

Now when running **sbt package** a rather confusing pair of messages is displayed: SUCCESSFUL but also NOT FOUND:

```
  [info] Resolving org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark ...
[info] downloading file:/C:/Users/S80035683//.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka/0.7.2-spark/kafka-0.7.2-spark.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark!kafka.jar (9ms)
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark!kafka.jar(src) (1ms)
[warn] ==== Local Repo: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/S80035683//.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka/0.7.2-spark/kafka-0.7.2-spark-sources.jar
[info] downloading file:/C:/Users/S80035683//.m2/repository/net/sf/py4j/py4j/0.7/py4j-0.7.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] net.sf.py4j#py4j;0.7!py4j.jar (7ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark!kafka.jar(src)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark!kafka.jar(src)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three little letters: **src**

[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.apache.kafka#kafka;0.7.2-spark!kafka.jar**(src)** (1ms)

I have specified **withSources** in the LibraryDependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ..
 "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka" % "0.7.2-spark"
withSources  // here is the culprit!
)
```

I have commented that out

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ..
 "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka" % "0.7.2-spark"
// withSources
)
```

and it now builds